# Stereo Camera Geometry

Tags: stereo-3d

[This paper](http://pub1.willowgarage.com/~konolige/svs/disparity.htm) describes nicely the geometry of a stereo image system. I am trying to figure out, if the cameras tilted towards each other with a certain angle, how the calculation would change? I looked around but couldn't find any reference to tilted camera systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the calculation changes significantly. The rectified case (where both cameras are well-aligned to each other) has the advantage that you can calculate the disparity and the depth is proportional to the disparity. This is not the case in the general case.

When you introduce tilts, you end up with something called epipolar geometry. [Here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook1/HZepipolar.pdf) is a paper about this I just googled. In order to calculate the depth from a pixel-pair you need the fundamental matrix or the essential matrix. Both are not easy to obtain from the image pair. If, however, you have the geometric relation of both cameras (translation and rotation), calculating these matrices is a lot easier.

There are several ways to calculate the depth of a pixel-pair. One way is to use the fundamental matrix to rectify both images (although rectifying is not easy either, or even unique) and run a simple disparity check.